# Trying to deploy React Application to Amazon S3 bucket and only a client, server, and react-loadable.json file is added to the bucket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack

1. Created a yml action to deploy the react app to the S3 bucket

name: Production Build

on:
push:
branches: [ master ]
pull_request:
branches: [ master ]

jobs:

## This workflow contains a single job called "build"

build:
# The type of runner that the job will run on
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
# Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
steps:
  # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Configure AWS Credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
    with:
      aws-s3-bucket: ${{ secrets.AWS_PRODUCTION_BUCKET_NAME }}
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
    env:
      JWT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
      REACT_APP_AMPLITUDE: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_AMPLITUDE }}
  - name: Build React App
    run: npm install && npm run build
  - name: Deploy app build to S3 bucket
    run: aws s3 sync ./dist/ s3://firmconnect.io --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete --exclude '.git/*'
```

2. npm run build executes npm run client:build && npm run server:build in my package.json
3. npm run client:build executes "webpack --config webpack.client.build.config.js"
4. npm run server:build executes "webpack --config webpack.server.build.config.js"

I see both build.config.js files are creating a client and server folder, but this must not be the right way to build the production application because no index.html file is being created, nor any assets. How do you properly deploy a react application using webpack to Amazon S3?

Comment: Is that a github action?

Comment: ya, it's a github action @RodrigoM